# JQuery no Alerting success data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some ajax here that getting the response but not the alert success and goes for error

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#manual').click(function(){
    alert('a');
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/get_data_id",
      type: "POST",
      data: { tag: $('#manual_text').val() },
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function()
      {
        alert("Error");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: How are you confirming that it is "getting the response"?  What is the "response" that it's getting?

Comment: Use the arguments in the error callback as outlined in the documentation to help sort out what error is. Or inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. There simply isn't enough detail here other than *"it doesn't work"*

Comment: from network responce in browser

Comment: i got response there in inspect browser but not success